# Hide popup is appearing while page is loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS 2010 for developing a web application. I used modal popup for adding/editing some information in page and the panel have the property `visible = false` or style `display: none`.

But when page is loading at that time all the pop up is appearing for a time being and then it is disappearing.

So how can I avoid the appearing/disappearing of the popup while page loading?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the style using javascript and call this function on OnOkScript/OnCancelScript of modal popup.

ex

function hide()    {    document.getElementById('<%=MyPanel.ClientID%>').style.display='none';    }